# Google Drive File open in iFrame

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api

I have problem with Drive Files, When I open file with in iFrame.  Sharing option in File Menu is disable and also sharring button is diabled on right top corner, Even I have the full permission of file.

Comment: what is the embed code you are using?

Comment: only iframe and src of file